# issue on redirecting on log in page when already log in in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, roles

im having a hard time trying to solve this issue. when i input a username and a password ive always redirect again in log in page. why this happen???

here's my code in login

account controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                     if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Employer"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("CustomerIndex", "Customer");
                    }
                     else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Worker"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("WorkerIndex", "Worker");
                    }
                     else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
                     {
                         return RedirectToAction("ClientIndex", "Client");
                     }
                     else 
                     {
                         return View(model);
                     }

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

thanks.for those who willing to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code there are 3 possible cases when this can happen:

1. Model validation failed -> for example the user didn't provide a username
2. The user provided incorrect credentials and the ValidateUser method returned false
3. Credential validation succeeded but the user is not in any of the roles `Employer`, `Worker` or `Administrator`.

Put a breakpoint in your code to see which is your case and act accordingly.

Comment: i tried to put a break point, at first log in when i login and click f10 in my controller it goes in all the condition. but when i log in at second it goes in the controller and in what role of that account was.mmmm